# no US point of contact. how should i proceed with US visa application

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

I am planning to travel to US with my family.
while filling the US visa application form, it is mendatory to provide a US point of contact, i enquired with my family, friends and relatives but found no one known in US.

How do i apply for US visa with out this information. Can anyone help finding solution for this?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type N/A if the field requires you to provide something.

Or you can put the name of the hotel you'll be staying at.

Comment: i read on many forums, that if i dont have a known person, i can write the hotel address and put all 9's in contact number. is that correct information?

Comment: actually the hotel we'll be staying at isn't fixed yet.

Comment: @Gunnrryy Yes! Putting 0's would be better though

Comment: if you dont mind, can you provide me any source where i can verify that.. dont mind.. just worried.

Comment: @Gunnrryy There's many things to be "worried" about - this is **not** one of them. If I'm not mistaken, there's should be a Checkbox saying "DO NOT KNOW" - in that case feel free to check it if you haven't decided on a hotel

Comment: there are 2 options, contact person in US OR Organisation.
i can tick DO NOT KNOW in any one of them, and the other becomes mendatory.

Comment: In that case, in "Organisation", type in any hotel in the City that you're going to that you might stay at. You can change it later if you book it before the visa interview

Comment: @Gunnrryy are you a citizen of one of the six.travel ban countries?

Comment: nope, we are Indian citizen. @phoog